# Convert vector into matrix

Tags: matrices, vectors

I have a vector $v\in\mathbb{R}^{mn\times 1}$ and I would like to make a matrix out of it in such form:
$$V=\begin{bmatrix}v_{1} & v_{2} & \dots & v_{m} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \dots & \vdots\\ v_{(n-1)m+1} & v_{(n-1)m+2} & \dots & v_{mn}  \end{bmatrix}$$

Is there a mathematical way to do so?

Comment: This operation called "reshape()" in Matlab for example, has, up to my knowledge, no simple writing in terms of usual matrix/vectors classical operators such as transposition, invertion, trace, det,...

Comment: I would like to find a mathematical way of doing the reshaping...

Comment: Yes, there is a mathematical way to do so. I'd tell you what it is, but you wrote it down yourself in your question. Which leaves me wondering what in the world you think a "mathematical way" means?